# What is the standard definition of recursive automata (or state machines)?

Tags: turing-machines, automata, finite-automata, recursion, research

I found this paper:

https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs373/fa2009/recaut.pdf

But it looks like recursion is done along an edge.  I would have thought you have state machines nested inside nodes.  Then there is an single, innermost (one of many) state machine that is running at any given moment.  However, I think that nodes along the super-node chain should also have the conditions or input tokens along *their* edges checked as well.  This allows a super-node to short-circuit ("at its level of business") the nested state machine, and so possibly more expressiveness, and at the worst case more convenience.

Question:
What is the standard definition of finite state machine?  Is their another definition that more closely behaves like I describe above?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm also interested.

Comment: @RoryByrne Never did.  I guess you just make up the definition for whatever your purposes are.  May I ask: what are you working on, sir?